# How do I use twig templates with views?

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to figure out how to use twig templates with views. at the moment I'm just using twig in the view itself but I'm sure I can use twig files to overwrite the styling of the view.

e.g.

```
<div class="editorHover">
<div class="editorInside">
        {{ field_category }}
        {{ title }}
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this in the rewrite field of the block view with one field hidden.

How can I translate this to a twig file?

[image]

Edit1; I'll try to explain my issue in more detail. I've been working with the page.html.twig file which overwrites the default homepage used by Drupal. I'm wondering if I can do the same with blockviews. Can I overwrite the default layout, meaning html layout, divs, classes, ID's using a Html.twig file for the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite `views-view-fields.html.twig` or create your personal `views-view-fields--YourViewName.html.twig` and apply the div or any wrapper you want.
 
I advise you to activate the twig debug to follow the suggestions

Comment: Does it automatically detect the template or do you have to apply it to the view?

Comment: I think it's automatically, beacause these are standards, to make sure enable the twig debug

Answer (score 2):

To create custom template for view create a file called  **views-view-fields--view_name--page/block.html.twig**. Save this file in your theme's template directory.

In this file define your html structure and specify the fields you want to display in your view like {{ fields.field_name.content }}.

It is mandatory that the fields your specifying in template file must be added to view through admin view, otherwise it will not be displayed in custom view template.
Once your template file is saved clear the cache to take effect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2118743 causes missing file name suggestions when using views **as blocks**.

To style them, you have to know the pattern, and contrary to what would seem obvious, you don't need to create a template for a block, but for a view.

It is
`views-view--<view-name-goes-here>.html.twig` in `<theme>/templates/views`